# Are there any tutorials/resources for generating objects in random locations?

Tags: modeling, python, scripting, objects

I'd like to write a script that places 3 objects of my choosing in random places in all xyz dimensions (with constant size, but varying rotations and locations) and I'm wondering where I should go to learn about this. E.g. if I want my 3 objects to be a sphere, cube, and cube, I'd like to be able to generate and save x number of random configurations of these objects.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95616/generate-x-cubes-at-random-locations-but-not-inside-each-other

Comment: Welcome to bse. IMO best place to learn this stuff is right inside blender using the python console. Type in `C.object.location = (1, 2, 3)` for example. Break the problem down, generating objects,  setting object rotation / location,  generating random numbers.  A quick search on "random location" here produced link above.  Asking for tutorials links _et al_ is somewhat open ended.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was just wondering if there was any documentation or textbook or anything sort of definitive to give me an overview on scripting for blender. Your advice is already helpful, thank you

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/