# Efficient way to fill up 3D space with cubes of different sizes?

Tags: modeling, python, scripting, mathematics

I'm working on a script that will generate `num_cubes` number of cubes in a pre-defined 3D space. The cube dimensions will be random, using `random.choice(cubeLengths)`, where `cubeLengths = [1,2,4]` (I will play with weights afterwards to make it more interesting).

I'd like to have it so that the cubes are as close together as possible without overlap, instead of having a lot of space in between them. I'd looked through [this answer dealing with overlapping cubes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95616/generate-x-cubes-at-random-locations-but-not-inside-each-other) that has a similar concept, and I was able to make that work, but I'm looking to make mine more compact, to achieve a specific look like this:

[image: Credit to David Mignot]

From the looks of things, it does not seem like his cubes overlap. Currently, I'm able to generate a single row of randomly sized cubes back-to-back, but then once I need to go to a second row, I get stuck. My code is obviously not optimized, nor is it the best, but here's what I have so far:

[image: My attempt]

What could be the right approach to tackling this problem? Am I overthinking this? Or is this specific problem require a lot more math than it seems?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Here's a more modern solution to this problem, using `Numpy` and the built-in `KDTree` algorithm in Blender's mathutils. It generates random points for our cubes, then prevents overlaps by measureing the distance between each cube and its closest neighbor.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
from mathutils import kdtree, Vector
import math

xmin, ymin, zmin = [ -5, -5, -5 ]
xmax, ymax, zmax = [ 5, 5, 5 ]
n = 500 # Number of cubes / density

x = xmin + np.random.random(n) * (xmax-xmin)
y = ymin + np.random.random(n) * (ymax-ymin)
z = zmin + np.random.random(n) * (zmax-zmin)
cube_centers =  np.array(list(zip(x,y,z)))

# For each point we'll find the nearest neighbor, 
# and we'll set the radius of the current point to be the distance from the closest point * gap
gap = 1 / math.sqrt(2) # This value ensures no overlap - if you want a higher density and don't care about overlaps you can increase this value
kd = kdtree.KDTree(n) # A KDtree algorithm helps quickly calculate distances between points

for i, v in enumerate(cube_centers):
    kd.insert(Vector(v), i)

kd.balance()

radii = []
for cc in cube_centers:
    co, index, dist = kd.find_n(Vector(cc), 2)[1]
    radii.append(dist*gap)
    
# Add the cubes
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add( size = radii[0], location = cube_centers[0] ) # First cube
cube = bpy.context.scene.objects['Cube']

# Add all other cubes
for cc, r in zip( cube_centers[1:], radii[1:] ):
    dupliCube = cube.copy()
    dupliCube.location = cc
    dupliCube.scale    = [r / cube.dimensions[0]]*3
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link( dupliCube )
```